# Symfony2 TitleCase in Bundle name produces namespacing errors and bundle configuration

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, namespaces, symfony-2.1

When generating a bundle, are TitleCase names valid? For example with `Acme\TitleCaseBundle` Symfony2 will automatically assume routes are to be prefixed with `acme_title_case`, services are `acme_title_case.example:` and in `Acme\TitleCaseBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration`, the root node for the configuration tree is found with this method

```
<?php
// ...

public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
{
    $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
    $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('acme_title_case');
    // ...
}
```

It's supposed to be `acme_titlecase` !

Trying to correct these, then adding `acme_titlecase: ~` to `app/config/config.yml` will throw this error

```
InvalidArgumentException: There is no extension able to load the configuration for 
"acme_titlecase" (in /Users/me/Sites/MySite/app/config/config.yml).
Looked for namespace "acme_titlecase", 
found "framework", "another_namespace", ... , "acme_title_case", ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [a post by Matthias Noback](http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2011/11/symfony2-define-your-bundles-configuration-values-using-the-treebuilder/), the solution is to override `getAlias()` method and return whatever you like.

```
<?php

namespace Acme\TitleCaseBundle\DependencyInjection;

// ...

class AcmeTitleCaseExtension extends Extension
{
    // ...

    public function getAlias()
    {
        return 'acme_titlecase';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a valid name, but making each word starting with capital letter you telling symfony this is a seperate word, so TitleCase is Title Case, it should be named TitlecaseBundle.